# Create table with text entries in Appsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-appsheet

I am making an app with appsheet in which user is asked to measure some values and enter numbers in a table, can i create this table in Appsheet?

Comment: Welcome. When you say "appsheet", do you mean [appsheet.com](https://www.appsheet.com/)? If so, what's the relevance to google-sheets?

Comment: Thanks Tedinoz for your interest. I am just using spreadsheet in Google sheet to register the inputs from the created app by appsheet

Comment: There are several questions about Google Sheets and Appsheet on Stackoverflow, StackExchange(webapps), and AppSheet itself. Would you summarise the research that you have already done - we wouldn't want to duplicate that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty big question that actually digs into how AppSheet works.

Ultimately, you will need to attach a data source (Google Sheets in this instance) to your appsheet app. Once you have done this In Data->Columns you can specify the type of data you are wanting to display/collect.

Again, this is actually a multi step process, but if you are looking for more information, these are some good options that I would recommend:

Official AppSheet resources:

AppSheet Documentation: https://help.appsheet.com/en/

AppSheet Forums: https://community.appsheet.com/

Recources from the #1 AppSheet partner:

A helpful YouTube Channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpUqfy0-plYV7OAno2Hohug

A paid tool that will soon be doing webinars: https://appsheettraining.com/